# Razor page URL Routing migration from Webforms

Tags: asp.net, url, routes, razor-pages

I'm migrating a Webforms application where the routing is set in a function that runs from Global.asax as follows:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("RouteName", "routeurl", "~/SitePage/SubDirectory/PageName.aspx");
RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("RouteName2", "routeurl/routewithsubname", "~/SitePage/SubDirectory/PageName2.aspx");
```

In the .Net Core solution, I have a directory called Pages which also includes subdirectories, and I want to keep the urls without mapping them to the directory structure of the solution.

I tried the Page directive `@page "/routeurl/routewithsubname"` but it's not working - I get a 404.

In Webforms, it's just one line of code but it seems more complicated in .Net Core, so how do I link a .cshtml page in the solution with a URL?

Comment: What does "it's not working" actually mean? You get a server error? 404?

Comment: Yes, I get a 404

Comment: And you are navigating literally to `/routeurl/routewithsubname`?

Comment: Yes, copy-pasted the route that's in the page directive. The actual url is obviously different, /routeurl/routewithsubname is just a generalization

Comment: Do you have `app.UseRouting()` followed by `app.MapRazorPages` in your Program.cs?

Comment: Yes. I also have this : app.MapControllerRoute(name: "default", "pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"); Could this be the reason?

Comment: When I'm in the solution directory and I right-click on the page and then click on View in Browser, it also returns a 404

Comment: Adding controllers shouldn't interfere with routing to pages, but right click - View in Browser tries to launch the page with its default folder-based route, not the override route in the `@page` directive. The default route gets overridden when you prefix the template with a forward slash. I'm afraid I'm out of ideas.